# split a number and create an orderedlist

Tags: xslt

```
<orderedlist type="manual">
        <item num="8. (1)">
            <para id="t2_HKWB-S2-1.1_pgfId-135">What is your present estimate of the length of trial?</para>
        </item>
        <item num="(2)">
            <para id="t2_HKWB-S2-1.1_pgfId-136">What is the earliest date that you believe you can be ready for trial?</para>
        </item>
    </orderedlist>
```

This is a slight tricky one as here, first the number 8. (1) should be split. 8 should be in an orderedlist and then 1 and 2 should be in same orderedlist(nested), under the main orderedlist, please let me know how i can achieve this.

i'm already trying with an xsl and it is as below.

```
<xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="orderedlist">
    <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="orderitem" match="item">
    <li class="item">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="orderitempara" match="item/para">



    <div class="para">

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=1">

                <span class="item-num">
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="parent::item[1]/@num"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </span>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </div>

</xsl:template>
```

But the output i get is like below:

```
   8. (1)What is your present estimate of the length of trial?
   (2)What is the earliest date that you believe you can be ready for trial?
```

should look something like this.

```
8  (1)What is your present estimate of the length of trial?
   (2)What is the earliest date that you believe you can be ready for trial?
```

Thanks

Comment: Two things a) You have to - as you said - split the string `"8. (1)"` into its components. However, you have to give a little more information as to the format of the string. Would `"[0-9]+\. *\([0-9]+)"` be a good regex to describe it? You could use e.g. `string-before|after` in XSLT 1.0 or `analyze-string()` in XSLT 2.0 to achieve this. b) Since your output format appears to be `text` you will have to do some extra effort to left-align the indented sections. Provided that you know the length of the first number you could use e.g. `substring` on an empty string for the padding.

Comment: Hi @MarcusRickert, Thanks for the suggestion, i use XSLT 1.0, here i want to create it as nested lists. please let me know how i can do it. Thanks Again.

Comment: OK. One more thing is missing: How will the next top level list entry be triggered? Do you have tag above `orderedlist` or shall the list entry be triggered by the existence of the `"[0-9]+\."` portion of your numbering? It would be best if you extended your input file to clarify this. By the way:  I just spotted the `<span>` tag in your XSLT. So this hints at an HTML output although your result above is shown as text. Could you edit your XSLT and/or output to make this more consistent? Thanks!